# Attempted import error: 'MDBCarouselInner' is not exported from 'mdb-react-ui-kit'

Tags: reactjs, mdbreact

I'm building a testimonial slider using the [mdb-react-ui-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdb-react-ui-kit) but I'm getting this error message: `Attempted import error: 'MDBCarouselInner' is not exported from 'mdb-react-ui-kit'`.

Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-jang-1pzotz?file=/src/App.js

My Code:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  MDBCarousel,
  MDBCarouselInner,
  MDBCarouselItem,
  MDBContainer,
  MDBRow,
  MDBCol,
  MDBIcon,
} from "mdb-react-ui-kit";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MDBContainer className="my-5">
      <MDBCarousel showControls dark>
        <MDBCarouselInner>
          <MDBCarouselItem className="active text-center">
            <img
              src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20(10).webp"
              alt="avatar"
              className="rounded-circle shadow-1-strong mb-4"
              style={{ width: "150px" }}
            />
            <MDBRow className="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <MDBCol lg="8">
                <h5 className="mb-3">Maria Kate</h5>
                <p>Photographer</p>
                <p className="text-muted">
                  <MDBIcon fas icon="quote-left" className="pe-2" />
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus
                  et deleniti nesciunt sint eligendi reprehenderit reiciendis,
                  quibusdam illo, beatae quia fugit consequatur laudantium velit
                  magnam error. Consectetur distinctio fugit doloremque.
                </p>
              </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
            <ul className="list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-center text-warning mb-0">
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon far icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </MDBCarouselItem>

          <MDBCarouselItem className="text-center">
            <img
              src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20(32).webp"
              alt="avatar"
              className="rounded-circle shadow-1-strong mb-4"
              style={{ width: "150px" }}
            />
            <MDBRow className="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <MDBCol lg="8">
                <h5 className="mb-3">John Doe</h5>
                <p>Web Developer</p>
                <p className="text-muted">
                  <MDBIcon fas icon="quote-left" className="pe-2" />
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus
                  et deleniti nesciunt sint eligendi reprehenderit reiciendis.
                </p>
              </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
            <ul className="list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-center text-warning mb-0">
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon far icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </MDBCarouselItem>

          <MDBCarouselItem className="text-center">
            <img
              src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20(1).webp"
              alt="avatar"
              className="rounded-circle shadow-1-strong mb-4"
              style={{ width: "150px" }}
            />
            <MDBRow className="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <MDBCol lg="8">
                <h5 className="mb-3">Anna Deynah</h5>
                <p>Web Developer</p>
                <p className="text-muted">
                  <MDBIcon fas icon="quote-left" className="pe-2" />
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus
                  et deleniti nesciunt sint eligendi reprehenderit reiciendis,
                  quibusdam illo, beatae quia fugit consequatur laudantium velit
                  magnam error. Consectetur distinctio fugit doloremque.
                </p>
              </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
            <ul className="list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-center text-warning mb-0">
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon fas icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <MDBIcon far icon="star" size="sm" />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </MDBCarouselItem>
        </MDBCarouselInner>
      </MDBCarousel>
    </MDBContainer>
  );
}
```